# Error Code MySQL Workbench: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, database

```
CREATE TABLE Estudante (
Matrícula int,
RG int,
Nome varchar(20),
Email varchar(20),
Endereço_atual  varchar(20),
Telefone_atual varchar(20),
Endereço_permanente varchar(20),
Telefone_permanente varchar(20),
Data_de_nascimento date,
Sexo varchar(1),
Série varchar(3),
Grau varchar(10),
Curso varchar(20),
PRIMARY KEY(Matrícula,RG)
);

CREATE TABLE Professor (
Matrícula int,
RG int,
CPF int,
Nome varchar(10),
Classificação varchar(3),
Endereço varchar(20),
Email varchar(10),
PRIMARY KEY(Matrícula,RG,CPF)
);

CREATE TABLE Departamento (
Nome varchar(20),
Código_departamento int,
Matrícula_prof int,
Ramal varchar(10),
Campus varchar(10),
PRIMARY KEY(Nome,Código_departamento),
CONSTRAINT FK_MatriculaProf FOREIGN KEY(Matrícula_prof) REFERENCES Professor (Matrícula)
);

CREATE TABLE Disciplina (
Código int,
Departamento_resp int,
Nome varchar(20),
Descrição varchar(20),
Carga_horária varchar(10),
Duração varchar(10),
Nível varchar(10),
PRIMARY KEY(Código),
CONSTRAINT FK_DepartamentoResp FOREIGN KEY(Departamento_resp) REFERENCES Departamento (Código_departamento)
);

CREATE TABLE Turma (
ID_Turma int,
Disciplina int,
Matricula_Instrutor int,
Período_aplicação varchar(10),
Ano int,
PRIMARY KEY(ID_Turma),
CONSTRAINT FK_Disciplina FOREIGN KEY(Disciplina) REFERENCES Disciplina (Código),
CONSTRAINT FK_MatriculaInstrutor FOREIGN KEY(Matricula_Instrutor) REFERENCES Professor (Matrícula)
);

CREATE TABLE Relatório_Notas (
Matricula_Estudante int,
Turma int,
Disciplina int,
Notas int,
PRIMARY KEY(Matricula_Estudante),
CONSTRAINT FK_MatriculaEstudante FOREIGN KEY(Matricula_Estudante) REFERENCES Estudante (Matrícula,RG),
CONSTRAINT FK_Turma FOREIGN KEY(Turma) REFERENCES Turma (ID_Turma),
CONSTRAINT FK_Disciplina FOREIGN KEY(Disciplina) REFERENCES Disciplina (Código)
);
```

The 3 first tables are ok, but on the "Disciplina" table I got this error:
Error Code MySQL Workbench: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define a foreign key as

```
CONSTRAINT FK_DepartamentoResp FOREIGN KEY(Departamento_resp) REFERENCES Departamento (Código_departamento)
```

but there is no index starting with column Código_departamento on the parent table.

If you change the primary key on `Departamento` from `(Nome,Código_departamento)` to `(Código_departamento, Nome)` (reverse column order) or add an extra index on `(Código_departamento)` things should work.

In general a `SHOW WARNINGS` after receiving an **Cannot add foreign key constraint** error reveals more detailed information on the problem.

Comment: Really on "Turma"? That one works for me, but "Relatório_Notas" fails with "ERROR 1239 (42000): Incorrect foreign key definition for 'FK_MatriculaEstudante': Key reference and table reference don't match", and this is due to "CONSTRAINT FK_MatriculaEstudante FOREIGN KEY(Matricula_Estudante)" listing a single column while "REFERENCES Estudante (Matrícula,RG)" has two columns ... looks as if the extra ",RG" isn't needed there?