# Doctrine: ManyToX relation between entities with composite keys

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have three entites, let’s call them `Site`, `Category` and `Tag`. In this scenario, `Category` and `Tag` have a composite ID generated from the `Site` entity and an external ID which is not unique (`site` and `id` together are unique). `Category` has a many-to-many relation on `Tag`. (Although my issue is also reproducible with ManyToOne relations.)

The `Site` entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Site
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $name;
}
```

The `Category` entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Category extends AbstractSiteAwareEntity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag")
     */
    private $tags;
}
```

The `Tag` entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Tag extends AbstractSiteAwareEntity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $name;
}
```

The last two entities inherit from the `AbstractSiteAwareEntity` class, which defines the composite index:

```
abstract class AbstractSiteAwareEntity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Site")
     */
    public $site;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    public $id;
}
```

As an example of a ManyToOne relation, let’s imagine a `Post` entity, which has an auto-increment ID and a reference to `Category`:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Post
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category")
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $content;
}
```

When updating the schema with `bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql --force --complete`, I get the following exception:

> An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE category_tag ADD
>   CONSTRAINT FK_D80F351812469DE2 FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES
>   Category (id) ON DELETE CASCADE':
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table
>   `xxxxxxx`.`#sql-3cf_14b6` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is
>   incorrectly formed")

I’m not sure what might be wrong … is there an error in my entity definitions? Or is this a Doctrine bug?

NOTE: I’m using doctrine/dbal 2.6.3 on Symfony 3.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Jannis’ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49395873/3908235), I was finally able to find a solution for this. The solution consists of two parts:

The first part is bit weird: Apparently Doctrine needs the `$id` before the `$site` reference in the composite primary key defined in `AbstractSiteEntity`. This sounds strange, but it’s definitely true, because I tried swapping them several times back and forth, and only this order works for some reason.

```
abstract class AbstractSiteAwareEntity
{
    // $id must come before $site

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Site")
     */
    public $site;
}
```

For ManyToMany relations, the indices in the JoinTable must be declared explicitely, because Doctrine failed to create a composite foreign key by itself. I used Jannis’ proposal for this with a few modifications (column names aren’t actually neccessary):

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(
 *  joinColumns={
 *      @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id"),
 *      @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="site_id")
 *  },
 *  inverseJoinColumns={
 *      @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id"),
 *      @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="site_id")
 *  }
 * )
*/
private $tags;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the **joined columns** in the annotation to make it work:

For a ManyToOne relation:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Tag")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tag_site_id", referencedColumnName="site_id"),
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 **/
protected $tag;
```

For a ManyToMany relation:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="category_tags",
 *      joinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_site_id", referencedColumnName="site_id"),
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *     },
 *      inverseJoinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tag_site_id", referencedColumnName="site_id"),
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *     }
 *      )
 **/
 protected $tags;
```

How it works: 2 columns are created as a **FOREIGN KEY** that **REFERENCES** the composite foreign key.

Note: In "@ORM\JoinColumn" setting:

- "referencedColumnName" setting is an id column name on the related table, so this should already exist.
- "name" is the column name that stores the foreign key and to be created and in case of ManyToOne, it should not conflict with any of the columns of the entity.

The order of your **joinColumns** definitions is important. The composite foreign key should start with a column that has **an index** in the referenced table. In this case, **"@ORM\JoinColumn" to "site_id"** should be **first**. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27150911/error-code-mysql-workbench-1215-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint)

Comment: Your code for ManyToMany works fine, I just have problems with the ManyToOne example. Could you change it to show how it would be if  Tag was related to Category with ManyToOne, where Tag has an auto-increment ID and Category the composite of site and external ID?

Comment: I edited the ManyToOne relation a few minutes ago because I had that one wrong, can you try again? What error do you get?

Comment: I have already tried that one. My actual entities are named a bit different, but the error is `Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed`, the query generated by D2 is `ALTER TABLE Tag ADD CONSTRAINT FK_… FOREIGN KEY (category_id, category_site_id) REFERENCES Category (id, site_id) ON DELETE CASCADE`. I’m not sure if I “translated” the column names in your example correctly.

Comment: You translated it correctly, but maybe the Tag table already has "category_id" or "category_site_id" columns? Can you check that?

Comment: @lxg it would be helpful if you can edit your question and add the ManyToOne relation you have and also the OneToMany if defined bidirectional in Category?

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your efforts. I have added an example for a (unidirectional) ManyToOne relation. I have tried different variations of your proposed solution, but they all give me either `Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed` or `Key reference and table reference don't match`. I think I might give up in favour of a simple auto-increment ID and just keep the composite key as an additional index.

Comment: @lxg Try to reverse the order in your @ORM\JoinColumns definition, put "category_site_id" first. Can you add the definition you used in your example?

Comment: @lxg, the order is actually the issue, Category(id) does not have an index, where Category(site_id) does. Reverse the order of "@ORM\JoinColumn" definitions and it will work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27150911/error-code-mysql-workbench-1215-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint

Comment: I tried this, too … it didn’t work either. Maybe there’s some other issue with my entities. Sorry, man, I think I’m giving up on this. I have now implemented the solution with auto-increment ID and the composite key as extra index, which works flawlessly. I’m giving you the +1 for your efforts, but unfortunately, we weren’t able to fix the problem. Thanks again.

Comment: I decided to give it a final try, and – believe it or not – I was able to solve it: Apparently the order of the `$id` and `$shop` properties is relevant for some reason! I’ve posted an answer with the final solution.

Comment: I could never have imagined that! Consider creating an issue at doctrine s repo, the least they can do is provide with some better documentation on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use composite PrK key for relations.
Instead, define an ID, and a composite UNI key (or just UNI key in this case)

<kbd>**Composite UNI key example**</kbd>

```
/**
 * SiteAware
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="site_aware",
 *     uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(columns={"site_id", "random_entity_id"})})
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"site", "randomEntity"}, message="This pair combination is already listed")
 */
abstract class AbstractSiteAwareEntity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    public $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Site")
     */
    public $site;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="RandomEntity")
     */
    public $randomEntity;
}
```

<kbd>**Simple unique key**</kbd>

```
abstract class AbstractSiteAwareEntity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    public $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Site")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(unique=true)
     */
    public $site;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Are you sure that PKs can’t be used for relations? According to the MySQL docs, it should be possible: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html.

Comment: Not sure about MySQL, but for sure, Symfony doesn't allow composite primary key to be used for relations. I came accros this problem myself.